# What is choice_set in this Django app tutorial?

Tags: python, django, orm

There is this line in the Django tutorial, *[Writing your first Django app, part 1](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)*:

```
p.choice_set.create(choice='Not much', votes=0)
```

How is `choice_set` called into existence and what is it?

I suppose the `choice` part is the lowercase version of the model `Choice` used in the tutorial, but what is `choice_set`? Can you elaborate?

**UPDATE:** Based on [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189179/ben-james)'s answer, I located this documentation: *[Following relationships "backward"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)*.

Comment: I should have just linked to that documentation, it is clearer than my answer.

Comment: @Ben James: no, I appreciate to have it formulated in a different way, especially the elaboration of what the ORM is doing. The Django documentation can be terse at times.

Comment: Thank you for asking this, I was confused by this as they do not explain it in the tutorial.

Comment: Wow, that's a loaded line of code for a newbie.  For me the hurdle was understanding that we're getting a Choice Object, related to the Question, in order to then increment it's choice.votes by one.  The RelatedManager concept has not been mentioned in the tutorial to this point so it can be a real stumbling block.

Comment: @PeterMortensen can you please update the documentation where it is described ? thank you

Comment: I belive the docs should be edited to accommodate an explanation to this.

Comment: @HemantKumar I tried to correct the docs but was not approved. If you find the same issue feel free to comment in the PR: https://github.com/django/django/pull/13330

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You created a foreign key on `Choice` which relates each one to a `Question`.

So, each `Choice` explicitly has a `question` field, which you declared in the model.

Django's ORM follows the relationship backwards from `Question` too, automatically generating a field on each instance called `foo_set` where `Foo` is the model with a `ForeignKey` field to that model.

`choice_set` is a `RelatedManager` which can create querysets of `Choice` objects which relate to the `Question` instance, e.g. `q.choice_set.all()`

If you don't like the `foo_set` naming which Django chooses automatically, or if you have more than one foreign key to the same model and need to distinguish them, you can choose your own overriding name using the [`related_name`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) argument to `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Thanks. I know much more now. Isn't choice_set a "Manager" ? (that can return an instance of class QuerySet). Or is it the same thing?

Comment: You're correct, it's a `RelatedManager` which can create querysets.

Answer (score 3):

Two crucial questions are raised here.

**First**: How is `choice_set` called into existence?

**Second**: What is it?

I will describe, how I made it easy for me while learning it first time. Let me address the second question first, "What is it" with the help of these 3 words: **Model Instance, Objects-set related to that instance, Related_manager**.

Models.py from Django tutorial:

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**Instance**:

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=3)
# Here q is an instance of model class 'Question'.

c = Choice.objects.get(pk=32)
# Here c is an instance of model class 'Choice'.
```

**Model Instance** is a single **ROW** of an entire **TABLE** of your database

Here, the `Question Model` is used as a `foreign key` to the `Choice Model`. Therefore, all the **objects-set related to instance q** can be filtered by using:

```
q.choice_set.all()
```

Therefore, `choice_set` here is, all the choices related to the question, that has pk=3.

Now, the answer to the first question needs the third word **Related Manager**. Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):-

> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will
> have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first
> model. By default, this Manager is named FOO_set, where FOO is the
> source model name, lowercase. This Manager returns QuerySets, which
> can be filtered and manipulated as described in the “Retrieving
> objects” section above.

This word (choice_set) can be changed using the 'related_name' parameter in the Foreign_key.

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="choices")
```

For backward relationships through foreign keys:

```
q.choice_set.all()
# If using related_name, then it is the same as 

q.choices.all()
# All the choices related to the instance q.
```

For forward relationship:

```
choice_qs = Choice.objects.all()
choice_qs.filter(question=q)
# Same result as above. All the choices related to instance q.
```