# Django Tutorial - Models explaination

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the url:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api

I'm unable to understand this line:

```
# Display any choices from the related object set -- none so far.
>>> q.choice_set.all()
```

q is an instance of Question, and no where we have defined the attribute `choice_set`, so how come it is working ?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048777/django-tutorial-what-is-choice-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django creates that attribute under the hood for you when you define your models, is part of django to 
provide that scaffolding to help you with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, you can read more about it in [Accessing related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/).