# What is choice_set.all in Django tutorial

Tags: python, django

In the Django tutorial:

```
       {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
```

I couldn't find a brief explanation for this. I know that in the admin.py file, I have created a foreign key of Question model on the choice model such that for every choice there is a question.

Comment: take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048777/django-tutorial-what-is-choice-set
I was looking for it a few minutes ago ;-)

Comment: the `.all` is the same 'all' as when you do `Choice.objects.all()` i.e. the queryset method. see @wim's answer for why

Comment: @Tom83B +1 for pointing to the right question with nice explanation.

Answer (score 28):

That's the Django metaclass magic in action!  Since you have a foreign key from `Choice` model to the `Question` model, you will automagically get the [inverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/) on instances of the `question` model back to the set of possible choices.

`question.choice_set.all` is the queryset of choices which point to your `question` instance as the foreign key.

The default name for this inverse relationship is `choice_set` (because the related model is named `Choice`).  But you can override this default name by specifying the `related_name` kwarg on the foreign key:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    ...
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='choices')
```

Comment: @wim good explanation, thanks. This is really confusing in the [Django tutorial documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/), because you're initially working with two db class models called `Question` and `Choice`, so `choice_set.all` makes you think there should be a method in your Choice class called `choice_set` or something.

Comment: This seems like a great place to update and improve the (already excellent) documentation.