# What are {% if error_message %}, {{ forloop.counter }} and choice_set.all things in Django form template?

Tags: django-templates

People! I am doing Django Tutorial.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form

I am stuck here. This is **detail.html** template code:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

I don't understand these things:

- {% if error_message %}
- {{ forloop.counter }}
- in question.choice_set.all value choice_set.all. Where does it come from?

The separete steps of the tutorial look clear, but then appear some peaces of code and clarity of what I am doing disappears.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit too late (5 months ago) but here is the answer for whom may read (me, i.e.) :

- `{% if error_message %}` mean that if we defined the `error_message` variable in the view, the template will display everything between the opening `{% if error_message %}` and `{% endif %}`
- `{{ forloop.counter }}` seems to be the equivalent of the classic `i` value, often encountered in PHP, C, C# etc using the `for(int i = 0; i < looptime; i++)`. This value is an integer, it will be set to it's value plus one every cycle and it start from 0. So during the first cycle, `i = 0` during the second `i = 1` etc… Here, `i` is `forloop.counter` (or more precisely the `counter` attribute of the `forloop` object, which may contains more infos about the forloop. Check doc to know more).
- In `question.choice_set.all` value `choice_set.all`, `choice_set.all` come from Django's DB API that you learnt to use at the beginning of the tuto (part 2 || 3). It's the same as `question.choice_set.all()` : it will list the choices related to this question. For more infos about this relation, check out [Django tutorial: What is choice_set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048777/django-tutorial-what-is-choice-set)

I hope my answer make you understand, I'm also a newbie in Django Framework: I started 3 days ago and I'm reading part 3 of tutorial so my answer may not be totally correct kappa