# Model method separation of concern

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Toy example: In my Django project, I have two apps: `Core` and `Blog`

**Core** app provides users functionality; User model, login logout, register etc

**Blog** app provides blogging functionality; Blogs, Comments, Categories etc

The subject of interest are the models:

```
# core/models.py

class User(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    ...
```

```
# blog/models.py

class BlogPost(models.model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('core.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

---

I'm using DRF and for one of my ViewSets in which I return a list of all BlogPosts for the currently logged in user. For this, I need to create a `QuerySet`

I can create a model method on the user object like so:

```
# core/models.py

class User(models.Model):
    ...

    def viewable_blogs(self):
        return BlogPost.objects.filter(owner=self.id)
```

And simply use it like this:

```
class BlogPostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.viewable_blogs.all()
```

---

This seems quite wrong to me and makes me a little uncomfortable since it breaks single responsibility principle. i.e The User Model should know nothing about other models.

I come from other frameworks like express, springboot etc, I'd create a `BlogService` and put the functionality of `viewable_blogs` in there:

```
class BlogPostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BlogService.getBlogsForUser(self.request.user)
```

Is there a Django recommended way to ensure encapsulation? Is making service classes a Django way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For related models (i.e., `User` and `BlogPost`), I think Django automatically creates a `RelatedManager` for your `User` instance with an attribute called `blogpost_set`.

So you should be able to fetch the blog posts for a particular user with something like:

```
user = User(pk=1)
user.blogpost_set.all()
```

This is basically the same functionality as you have done manually in your `viewable_blogs` method, but Django tends to favor using the built-in "managers" to do relational querysets. I would say creating a `BlogService` would probably not be the ideal since it adds an additional layer to the relationship between models and Python tends to favor the simpler approaches.

See:

- [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager)
- [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/)
- [Django tutorial: What is choice_set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048777/django-tutorial-what-is-choice-set)

Comment: That would work in this example but if I needed a more complex query like "return all the posts by this user **and** user's admin posts" then this wouldn't work

Comment: For more complex queries, you can create a custom manager to fetch the querysets  according to your criteria. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager

Comment: Glad this works for you! I've found that many of the concepts and design patterns from other languages can be expressed in Django using different terminologies but in some ways they are actually simpler once you get used to the Django way of doing things. Django is very good at making sure most of its features are highly customizable.