# How to create a ModelForm field based on a RelatedManager?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating a multiple choice quiz with the following `models.py`:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

This way, a question's choices can be accessed through its [RelatedManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2048806/5238059) `choice_set` e.g. `q.choice_set.all()`.

I don't know how to then create a [Radio Input Form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp) for each Question? I created the following `forms.py`:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['choices']
```

However, I'm not sure how I can create a field based on each question's `choice_set` and then have a radio input for each choice in each question's `choice_set`?

I want the end result to be `urls` that end up like this: `question/1`, `question/2`, etc. with the Question title, radio inputs for the choices and next and previous buttons (where applicable).

I have the following `FormView` and `template`:

`views.py`

```
class QuestionFormView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = QuestionForm
    model = Question
    template_name = 'quiz/question-form.html'
```

`question-form.html`

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, this form implementation does not seem very practical to me. There should be an answer model, which points to the `Question` model for question, and `Choice` model for choices. It should be like this:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    choices = models.ForeignKey(Choices, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Then you should design the form like this:

```
class QuestionAnswerForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['choices']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionAnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        question = self.initial['question']
        self.fields['choices'].queryset = question.choice_set.all()
```

Finally, update the view:

```
class QuestionFormView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = QuestionAnswerForm
    model = Answer
    template_name = 'quiz/question-form.html'
    
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(QuestionFormView, self).get_initial()
        initial['question'] = Question.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return initial
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way in form:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Choice.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['choices']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choices'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=self.instance.choices_set, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Comment: I still get a FieldError: Unknown field(s) (choices) specified for Question.